# User-Defined Function won't accept reactive dataframe in Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, function, shiny

So, I have defined the following function. I have verified it *works outside my shiny app*. However, when I attempt to integrate it into my app it only uses the first line of code in the function and returns it.

Get Sample Data:

```
library(quantmod); library(dplyr); library(broom)

AAPl <- getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = as.Date("2021-04-20"), to = as.Date("2021-05-01"), auto.assign = F )

xts1_df <- tidy(AAPL)
DF1 <- as_tsibble( xts1_df %>% filter(series == "AAPL.Open")) 

DF1
# A tsibble: 9 x 3 [1D] <UTC>
  index      series    value
1 2021-04-20 AAPL.Open  135
```

The function:

```
sellday <- function(x) {
      
    sellday <-c(rep(0, nrow(x))) #The line that seems to trip it in the app

      for (ii in 5:nrow(x)) {

          MA.5 <- mean( data.frame( x[(ii-4):(ii-1),3] )[,1]) #mov.avg on past days (rows) of DF

          if( x[ii,3] > MA.5 ) {
            sellday[ii] <- as.numeric(x[ii, 1]) #sell if above MA
                                #record day of sell based on position
          }} 

      return(sellday)
}
```

Shiny Server: *does the same as get data block but stock is user input*

```
*DFalgo is a reactive DF created from stock data by user input*
  DFalgo<-  # a tsibble with columns   index      series    value
                                       <date>     <chr>     <dbl>
  
  #### My function in server ####
  selldays <- reactive({ sellday(DFalgo()) })
  
  # output 
  
  output$algoselldays <- renderText( selldays() )
```

Output in Shiny App:

- if repping 0s `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Desired Output:

- I would like for it to be a vector of 0s same length as dataframe input, with certain spots filled in with dates for days to sell.

```
   0     0     0     0     0     0     0 18423
```

**It just reps whatever I put in the first line of the function and seems to ignore the rest of the function when I put it into my app**

Comment: If you want someone to help you please post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some sample data.

Comment: I’ve tried making it easier to follow, if anyone has any ideas please let me know

Comment: Your function works fine for me in Shiny.

Comment: Hmm, maybe my UI is truncating some of the output and just not showing me the first sell day. I will check on this

Thanks for the help!